# QT Creator Debugger Local Variable panel

Tags: c++, debugging, qt-creator

I stumbled over two questions with the current Debugger Local Variable panel

[image: Debugger Local Variable panel]

the first is the column 'time' [German: Zeit], which I do not even have the slightest clue what that should be. Can't remember ever working with a Debugger offering time for variables...

the second is the column 'value' [German: Wert], which I switched to hex display, expecting 0xfedcba9876543210 formatted values. How to read what they display now and why this strange format?

Bonusquestion: How one can set the hex-format back to the good old 0xfedcba9876543210 style?

Comment: OK, 2nd question solved: I choosed hex float format by mistake

Comment: QT Creator Debugger's [Local Variables panel](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-locals-view.html) does not show "Zeit" by default. You likely have customized displayed columns there.

Comment: @273K well no, at least I not even know where one would be able to configure that.